# (20.04) Laptop keyboard doesn't work, but only in certain cases and only on one user account

Tags: 20.04, grub2, keyboard, configuration

My laptop keyboard randomly stopped working, but only for one user account.
If I boot from recovery mode (advanced options for ubuntu -> linux xxx.xxx.xxx (recovery mode) -> continue) the keyboard works, but the touchpad stops working (which can be fixed by putting `modprobe -r psmouse; modprobe psmouse` in my `/etc/rc.local`) and my display is locked at the lowest brightness.

Things I've tried:

1. Putting `atkbd.reset` in my `/etc/default/grub`, which does nothing
2. Putting `modprobe -r atkbd; modprobe atkbd` in my `/etc/rc.local`, which doesn't work because atkbd is compiled into the kernel not as dynamic (I think that's why?)
3. Switching desktop environments, which doesn't work
4. Switching user accounts, which fixes it???
5. `apt reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`, which does nothing
6. Checking accesibility options, which are all off
7. `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, which didn't work
8. `dconf reset -f /org/gnome`, which does nothing

So, is there a way to fix this, either by just resetting that account's configuration, or by actually fixing the issue?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with one of the files in `~/.conf`. Have you configured any custom key mappings? 

Comment: You know what? I have! It doesn't make sense that it only breaks for one user (it's in `/etc/rc.local`) but I'll try removing it.

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't work.